# UPDATE mysql table from Oracle query

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

So I've seen posts of updating mysql table from mysql queries, but I can't seem to find the right answer for updating from an Oracle dbase query.  I've tried so many different ways of formatting this that now I'm just at a loss of things to try.  I'm not sure whether I need to be echoing the results of the oracle query or not.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and I'll be happy to try and explain anything that's not clear.  I'm not a programmer by any means, just basically teaching myself.

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    $SD = $_POST[SD];
    $ED = $_POST[ED];

    $db = '(DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=host)
      (PORT=port)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVICE_NAME=name)
    )
  )
';

    $c1 = oci_connect("user", "pass", $db);

    $sql = oci_parse($c1, "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'mm/dd/yyyy'");
    oci_execute($sql);
    $sql = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT ulid, itmcod, locatn, casqty, ctlgrp, expdat, subsit, qastat from invent_view");
        oci_execute($sql);
       $results = array();
while ($result = oci_fetch_array($sql)){
$results[] = $result;
foreach ($results as $result){
    $ULID = ($result['ULID']);
    $ITMCOD = ($result['ITMCOD']);
    $LOCATN = ($result['LOCATN']);
    $CASQTY = ($result['CASQTY']);
    $CTLGRP = ($result['CTLGRP']);
    $EXPDAT = ($result['EXPDAT']);
    $SUBSIT = ($result['SUBSIT']);
    $QASTAT = ($result['QASTAT']);
}
echo $ULID . '<br/>';

echo $ITMCOD . '<br/>';

echo $LOCATN . '<br/>';

echo $CASQTY . '<br/>';

echo $CTLGRP . '<br/>';

echo $EXPDAT . '<br/>';

echo $SUBSIT . '<br/>';

echo $QASTAT . '<br/>';
}
?>

<?php
$servername = "server";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "UPDATE `dbname`.`invent_view` SET `ULID` = '$ULID', `ITMCOD` = '$ITMCOD', `LOCATN` = '$LOCATN', `CASQTY` = '$CASQTY', `CTLGRP` = '$CTLGRP', `EXPDAT` = '$EXPDAT', `SUBSIT` = '$SUBSIT', `QASTAT` = '$QASTAT'";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo $stmt->rowCount() . "records UPDATED successfully";        
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: mysql and oracle are two different platforms.  get rid of all those back ticks.

Comment: Believe me I've tried every way I can think of.  With ticks and without.  Anything else stick out?

Comment: What is your error or undesired result? What's not working?

Comment: The query works and displays in the browser, but the mysql table is not updated.